# Why in a iTextSharp\iText cell I can't see all the textual content?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, itext

I have the following problem with iTextSharp (the C# porting of iText):

I have the following table:

```
PdfPTable vulnerabilityDetailsTable = new PdfPTable(3);
vulnerabilityDetailsTable.WidthPercentage = 98;


cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Vulnerability Details"));
cell.Colspan = 3;
cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right

vulnerabilityDetailsTable.AddCell(cell);

// CVE:
vulnerabilityDetailsTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("CVE")) { Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER, Padding = 5, FixedHeight = 45, PaddingTop = 20 });
vulnerabilityDetailsTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(currentVuln.CVE.ToString())) { Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER, Padding = 5, FixedHeight = 45, PaddingTop = 20 });
vulnerabilityDetailsTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("")) { Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER, Padding = 5, FixedHeight = 45, PaddingTop = 20 });

// Classification:
vulnerabilityDetailsTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Classification")) { Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER, Padding = 5, FixedHeight = 45, PaddingTop = 20 });
vulnerabilityDetailsTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(currentVuln.Classification.ToString())) { Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER, Padding = 5, FixedHeight = 45, PaddingTop = 20 });
vulnerabilityDetailsTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("")) { Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER, Padding = 5, FixedHeight = 45, PaddingTop = 20 });

......................................................................................
......................................................................................
......................................................................................

_document.Add(vulnerabilityDetailsTable);
```

The problem is related to the lenght of these cells:

```
vulnerabilityDetailsTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(currentVuln.CVE.ToString())) { Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER, Padding = 5, FixedHeight = 45, PaddingTop = 20 });

vulnerabilityDetailsTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(currentVuln.Classification.ToString())) { Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER, Padding = 5, FixedHeight = 45, PaddingTop = 20 });
```

The problem is that in thse cell I can't see all the textual content but only a portion because it is too long for the cell dimension.

What can I do to show all the content? Can I set that the cell\row height have to automatically set to the right height to show all my content?

Tnx

Answer (score 1):

Solved by myself replacing **FixedHeight = 45** with **MinimumHeight = 45**